# Git submodule update init "skipping"

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule (inside another submodule, and yes, I use `--recursive`) that will not init, although it is empty in the current state. `git submodule update --init --recursive` says "Skipping submodule '<submodule name>'", even with the `--force` option. In `.gitmodules` the submodule had option `update = none` but I removed that - to no avail.

In other, similar situations I ran git `submodule deinit --all -f` followed again by `git submodule update --init --recursive`. But it doesn't help this time around.

Any hints ?